# arduino using esp32 slow floating point Where is the native implementation library?

Tags: arduino, esp32

I am programming the esp32 using the arduino platform.
Using the code bellow it shows up that a simple calcuation of a sine takes almost 3000 cpu cycles. The esp32 has hardware support for floating point. So the expected cycles should be bellow 100 in any case.
There should be a way to use a library that uses the native capabilities of the processor.

The code to check timings of sin is bellow for reference.

```
void loop() {
  int ms=millis();double d=0;int n=100000;double clock=240000000;
  unsigned long c=xthal_get_ccount();
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){ d+=sin((i+0.5)*M_PI/n); }
  c=xthal_get_ccount()-c;
  ms=millis()-ms;double t=double(ms)/1000;
  Serial.print("d=");Serial.print(d);Serial.print(" t=");Serial.print(t),Serial.print(" clock cycles=");Serial.print(t/n*clock);Serial.print(" c=");Serial.print(c/n);Serial.println("");
  digitalWrite(L1,b=!b ? HIGH : LOW);
}
```

Comment: See all the  [discussions](https://www.esp32.com/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=800) on Espressif Forum.

Comment: Also [tests done in this blog](https://blog.classycode.com/esp32-floating-point-performance-6e9f6f567a69) that lead to the Espessif forum discussion.

Comment: I have already seen the above, but I am unable to figure out what is going on. Does the esp32 has the relative instructions and these are used ? If this is the case then if timings are as shown, then there is no FPU and floating point is emulated internally. Which is the truth ?

Answer (score 0):

The ESP32 has FPU hardware support for float's only.
Decimal values therefore also need the f postfix, or you end up using slow doubles... e.g 0.5f

```
void loop() {
  int ms=millis();float f=0;float n=100000;double clock=240000000;
  unsigned long c=xthal_get_ccount();
  for(float i=0;i<n;i++){ f+=sin((i+0.5f)*(float)M_PI/n); }
  c=xthal_get_ccount()-c;
  ms=millis()-ms;double t=double(ms)/1000;
  Serial.print("f=");Serial.print(f);Serial.print(" t=");Serial.print(t),Serial.print(" clock cycles=");Serial.print(t/n*clock);Serial.print(" c=");Serial.print(c/n);Serial.println("");
  digitalWrite(L1,b=!b ? HIGH : LOW);
}
```

Comment: You mean timings are different in that case?